# How to connect to an OpenERP mySql database from a sqlclient program (like HeidiSQL)

Tags: mysql, odoo

I have troubles to connect to a MySql Database server instaled in an ubuntu server from a PC with an SQLclient (like HeidiSQL) in the same local network.  This database server is part of the installation of a OpenErp (opensource project) and it is working properly.

I would like to develop a new program to extract some data from this dabase for BI purposes, but I'm havin connection problems.

I have tried connection via 3306, 8070 and other given ports but without success.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this modules to manage connections to a mysql server

https://github.com/OCA/server-tools/tree/10.0/base_external_dbsource_mysql

https://github.com/OCA/server-tools/tree/10.0/base_external_dbsource_sqlite

https://github.com/OCA/server-tools/tree/10.0/base_external_dbsource

Create a record like this one(manual using the form or in xml):

```
<record model="base.external.dbsource" id="read_mysql_conn" forcecreate="True">
    <field name="name">MySQL Connection</field>
    <field name="password">admin</field>
    <field name="connector">mysql</field>
    <field name="conn_string">mysql+pymysql://user:%s@127.0.0.1:3306/database</field>
</record>
```

Use it like this:

```
res = self.env.ref('custom_module.read_mysql_conn').execute(
    """Select `id`, `name`, `unit` from `units`;""",
    {}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Odoo is using Postgresql so the pgAdmin would be the best choice.

1. Get the pgAdmin (https://www.pgadmin.org/download/)
2. Allow connections from your IP in postgresql.config (uncomment the line "listen_addresses")
3. Adjust pg_hba.conf by adding:

   `host    all             all             your.public.ip/32         md5`
4. Connect using pgAdmin

Also, if you are using Amazon EC2 or other modern CLoud servers remember to allow port 5432  to be accessed from your IP.
Source: https://cier.tech/blog/blog-1/post/how-to-connect-to-odoo-db-using-pgadmin-20